# Cannot start chromium on vncserver without --no-sandbox option

Tags: google-chrome, debian, vnc, chromium, vncserver

I've got server with Debian 7.0 and I installed vnc4server with fluxbox and chromium (same happens on google chrome, though) on it. When I try to open chromium, I get this error:

```
PID namespaces supported Network namespace supportedbut failed: errno = Operation not permitted
```

From what I've read on the Internet, I have to start it --no-sandbox option. But is there any way I could run it without that option? It's a bit annoying.
THank you for any help.

Comment: FYI, this isn't VNC-related; I'm using Chrome under TigerVNC (which is better than basic TightVNC/RealVNC btw) right now; the only thing I have to live with is the lack of WebGL. I just run `google-chrome` and it works. Does this only occur if you're trying to run Chrome in VNC, or have you tried running Chrome on a physical X server? Possibly pastebin the output of `strace -f google-chrome 2>&1 | grep -C 200 EPERM`.